# Generated resource not working with ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm getting familiar with ember and can't seem to debug an issue I'm having with a generated resource. After generating a new app with ember-cli, I generated a resource:

`ember generate resource contacts`

This generated a few files, all seemed well. The problems began when attempting to list the contacts from a http-mock. I can see from the *network* tab in dev tools that the records are retrieved, but the view won't display them:

Model:

```
#app/models/contact.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Route:

```
#app/routes/contacts.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
       return this.get('store').find('contact');
   }
});
```

The view

```
#app/templates/contacts.hbs
<h2 id="title">Contacts</h2>

{{#each contact as |c|}}
  {{c.title}}
{{/each}}
{{outlet}}
```

JSON from http mock:

```
{
    "contacts": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Test"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, the problem was in my view `contacts.hbs`. Changed to:

```
<h2 id="title">Contacts</h2>

{{#each model as |c|}}
  {{c.title}}
{{/each}}
{{outlet}}
```

Thanks to @jacefarm on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235331/why-is-firebase-data-not-displaying-properly-in-my-ember-cli-generated-output?rq=1) question for putting me on the right track

Comment: `x in model` is deprecated, use `{{#each model as |c|}}`

Comment: Thanks for the pro-tip!